# How to remove plus.me from OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Today I've received email from Google, that claims my project uses one scope `plus.me` from Google+ API which will be shutdown.
I've already implemented Google Drive API usage with new OAuth 2.0 in my app. And was trying to find where it uses that Google+ scope.
The only place where this scope exists is in "OAuth consent screen" in Google APIs console.
[image: OAuth consent screen]
But there is no "Delete" button. So I'm wondering how could I remove it? I'm afraid with shutting down Google+ my requests to OAuth 2.0 could be denied :(

Comment: The email subject is "[Action Required] Google+ APIs and OAuth requests are being shutdown on March 7, 2019"

Comment: There is some useful info at https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown , which can help you confirm whether you need to change your scopes

Comment: I have the same problem. While I have not been able to confirm (pending approval), further down the list is 'openid' with a 'Delete' button. Do you have the same? Any effect?

Comment: @bshouse According to the screenshot, I do not have "delete" button in front of "openid" item at all.

Comment: even we are getting the same error after updating SDK. and when we debug using charles we are getting the response as : "grantedScopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me openid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew! Today got clarification from Google with subject "**[Correction] Google+ APIs being shutdown on March 7, 2019**".

> Earlier this week we sent you an email related to your projects that will be impacted by the Google+ API shutdown, which also affects requests for Google+ OAuth scopes.
>
> The email listed that one or more of your projects are requesting the
>   “plus.me” scope, and would thus be affected. We would like to clarify
>   that only projects directly requesting the “plus.me” scope are
>   affected. This scope may have been listed in some emails, even if not
>   directly requested by your project. We apologize for any confusion
>   caused.
>
> If you are directly requesting the “plus.me” scope, any other Google+
>   OAuth scopes, or making any Google+ API calls, please ensure that you
>   remove these requests from your project before March 7, 2019.
>
> To see if your project is directly requesting the “plus.me” or any
>   other Google+ OAuth scopes:
>
> If your project is written in Google Apps Script, you can view which scopes your project is requesting by reviewing your project
>   properties in App Script Editor.
>   If your project is not written in Google Apps Script, please check your code for references to “plus.me” in OAuth scope requests. We
>   recommend that you review projects using any 3rd-party libraries that
>   support sign-in or social functionality, as these may also be affected
>   by the shutdown.

So it seems we should not worry about the `plus.me` item any more. Just remove this scope from the code if we use it.